# Ternary computers: what would the third (unknown) part of a trit be used for?

Tags: binary, logic, computer-science, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I'm very interested in the idea of creating/designing (but most likely only imagining) a ternary computer rather than a binary computer.

If I were to do this, I would used a balanced base-3 system, so a trit *(trit is to base-3 as bit is to base-2)* could be -1, 0, or +1. Storing data using trits would be approximately 36% more compact than storing data using bits like we do on today's computers, however ternary arithmetic would be much more complicated so there's no telling whether an ALU using ternary-computing would be faster or slower than binary.

But I digress, that's just a little background stuff that doesn't entirely pertain to the question, but it is related. :)

So, possible values for a trit:

-1 is **off/false**, same as 0 in binary.

0 is **unknown**. No equivalent in binary.

+1 is **on/true**, same as 1 in binary.

My question is...what is the point of that 0 in terms of computing? For example, I've been reading up a lot on logic gates and I understand both how they work and how they can work together to create an ALU. A binary AND gate is very simple, and combined with other binary logic gates they could all be used in combination to perform arithmetic such as creating an Adder, or a unit that performs addition.

I can't even comprehend how this would be done using ternary-computing. How would the unknown (0) factor into the logic gates and be used to perform arithmetic? Hell, I can't even comprehend what outputs a ternary AND gate would put out and how they'd be used.

For example, I would assume for a ternary computer an AND gate would accept 3 inputs instead of 2. Let's call the inputs A, B, and C.

In a binary AND gate, A and B can be 0 or 1. There are four possible combinations of what A and B could be input into the AND gate as. This results in only four possible outputs from the AND gate. If A and B are both 1 then the AND gate outputs a 1. If it is any of the other three combinations of A and B then it outputs 0. (possible results from AND gate considering all possible A/B combinations: 0, 0, 0, 1)

A ternary AND gate would take in 3 inputs, right? So in a ternary AND gate, A, B, and C could be -1, 0, or 1. This means that there are 27 possible combinations for A/B/C. Rather than listing out the  possible outcomes for each combination, I'll just add them up for you guys. :)

Anyway, there is only one combination in which 1 will be the output, there are 7 combinations in which 0 will be the output (assuming if A, B, and C are all 0 the AND gate will output 0), and there are 19 combinations in which -1 will be the output. In a binary Adder if the gate throws a 1 it would be sent off to another gate to be evaluated and so on until the addition is complete. In ternary...what would a gate do if it received a 0?

**I know that's a lot of reading, so I'll try to sum it up and list the main questions below:**

How would the 0 of a trit in a balanced ternary system be used/handled in logic gates?

If a logic gate outputs a 0, and the gate is being used in an ALU to perform arithmetic (let's say addition for example), how would the gate that receives the 0 be expected to handle it? Basically, how would one go about creating an Adder using ternary logic?

And lastly, am I correct assuming that in a ternary computer logic gates would accept 3 inputs instead of 2 like binary computers, or would logic gates still be dyadic?

Comment: "A ternary AND gate would take in 3 inputs": no, AND is just a dyadic operation.

Comment: are you making a quantum computer in you cellar or something? :)

Comment: Nope, just a curious individual.

Answer (score 1):

An essential goal of ALU design is to perform arithmetic on integers. In the first place addition (subtraction), then multiplication and division.

When written in base 3, these operations are well defined. For instance

```
+ |  0  1  2
------------
0 |  0  1  2
1 |  1  2 10
2 |  2 10 11
```

As with binary arithmetic, on needs to compute a sum trit and a carry. When the carry is propagated, the following table applies

```
+c|  0  1  2
------------
0 |  1  2 10
1 |  2 10 11
2 | 10 11 12
```

So you indeed need two three-input functions (two trits in and a carry in), giving the sum trit and the carry out bit. (Notice that binary ALUs add the same way: two bits in and a carry in giving a sum and a carry out bit.)

Whether this can be implemented from elementary dyadic or triadic gates would be technology dependent.

The logical predicates AND/OR have no reason to be modified and should remain binary. Boolean arithmetic remains Boolean.

Besides, if you enumerate all ternary functions of two ternary arguments (i.e. 9 input combinations), you find 19683 of them. Contrast this to 16 binary functions. This mess is unmanageable. (Don't even think of all triadic ternary functions, 7625597484987 of them.)

Comment: Balanced ternary is in a lot of ways more appealing, though arithmetic is a little trickier since it has both positive and negative carries in the same operation.  Such complexity in addition, however, is balanced by simplicity in multiplication, since each term will only have to be multiplied by a power of three times +1 or -1, and multiplication by -1 merely requires flipping all P to N or vice versa.

Comment: @supercat: how will you represent integers using balanced trits ? I don't believe in this "lot of ways more appealing".

Comment: Integers -4 to +4 may be represented using two trits; the count sequence would be NN-4, then N0, NP, 0N, 00, 0P, PN, P0, PP.  The range extends to +/-13 with three trits, or +/-40 with four.  Balanced ternary notation has the advantage that every portion of a multi-precision signed number can be treated the same way, and the range of signed-integer types is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I believe I may have found the answer to my questions.

So, there's no reason to reinvent the wheel, using standard binary logic gates would work just fine in a ternary computer.

In binary, 0 is false and 1 is true, and a number in binary is to be read from right to left, each digit following a power of two. For example, 10010 would be 18 (2 + 16). This number system is incremental, meaning the more 1's you have to the left the higher the number would be if converted to decimal, but there's no way to decrement with this system. All of this is done using transistors that make use of only caring about whether there is voltage flowing through it or if there isn't, thus determining if there is voltage it is on, and the bit is a 1, and if not then it is off, and the bit is a 0.

In ternary, there wouldn't be an on/off. Unlike the standard transistor in binary computers that tests whether there is or isn't voltage to determine the bit's value, a transistor for a ternary computer would test for if the voltage is negative, positive, or a ground. (-1 being negative voltage, 0 being the ground, +1 being positive voltage).

Using this system, decimal numbers would be written in ternary similarly to how a decimal number would be written in binary with one exception: ternary allows for decrementation. Take a number in binary for example, with the first digit starting on the right the digits correlate to 2^0, then 2^1, and so on. In binary all the digits with 1's and their correlating power of 2 is then added up to give you your number.

Now imagine ternary. From right-to-left it would follow 3^0, 3^1, 3^2, and so on. *however*, a +1 trit would indicate that the power of 3 that the digit correlates to is positive, a 0 trit would mean that digit is ignored just as a 0 does the same in binary, and a -1 trit would mean that the power of 3 that the digit correlates to is negative. This allows for both incrementation and decrementation.

Take this ternary number for example: (I'm going to use '-' instead of '-1', and '+' to represent '+1': +-0+-

this would be, reading from left to right, (-1)+(3)+(-27)+(81) = 56

While it's true that ternary and dyadic logic gates are compatible, an ALU would have to be designed *very* differently. Basically that's it. :)